# Faking small caps in XeLaTeX

Tags: macros, tex-core, fontspec, small-caps

In the post [Fake small caps with XeTeX/fontspec?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55664/fake-small-caps-with-xetex-fontspec?rq=1) I have found the following definitions to fake small caps

```
   \def\mycommand{\bgroup\obeyspaces\mycommandaux}
   \def\mycommandaux#1{\mycommandauxii #1\relax\relax\egroup}
   \def\mycommandauxii#1{%
   \ifx\relax#1\else 
   \ifcat#1\@sptoken{}  
   \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\mycommandauxii\else
   \ifnum`#1=\uccode`#1 {\normalsize #1}\else {\footnotesize \uppercase{#1}}\fi   
   \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\mycommandauxii\expandafter\fi\fi}

   % ...

   \mycommand{This text is set in fake small caps.}
```

`\mycommand` works properly in the main text. However, when `\mycommand` is used inside other commands like `\title` of `\footnote` it removes the spaces between the words.

So I wonder if there is any way to make the above command to work inside other commands or if there are other ways to achieve the same result.

In the code above `\normalsize` and `\footnotesize` can be replaced some `\fontspec` instructions. An advantage of the approach (or similar) is that it could work for generic fonts without small caps (I am aware of `fontinst` and the support for creating small caps in fontforge)

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @MarcvanDongen The question is why does the posted code not work when used within another command like `\title` or `\footnote`.

Comment: It can't work: it's a verbatim-like approach as `\obeyspaces` alters the tokenization of spaces. You need to use an alternative token-by-token mapping that respects spaces. These are always a bit tricky!

Comment: Any suggestion on how to do the alternative token-to-token mapping?

Comment: @AlanMunn Thanks for the clarification. It was sort of clear but Guido would do himself a favour if he stated an explicit question.

Comment: @MarkvanDongen I have explicitly included a question, and clarified the background.

Comment: I'm not sure it should be considered an advantage that it works for generic fonts which lack small-caps. It will have all of the disadvantages of the fake small-caps supported by `fontinst`. (In fact, it will probably have significant disadvantages even over and above those which apply to that method.) Given that we have access to fonts with proper small-caps, it seems a shame to encourage the use of faked ones. (Just as faked slanted shapes are an extremely poor substitute for true italics.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A different approach: with `\fakesc` you can store the "faked" text in a control sequence for later use.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\fakesc}{ o m }
 {
  \guido_fakesc:n { #2 }
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
   {
    \tl_use:N \l__guido_temp_tl
   }
   {
    \cs_set_eq:NN #1 \l__guido_temp_tl
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \guido_fakesc:n #1
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l__guido_text_tl { #1 }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l__guido_text_tl { ~ } { \q_space }
  \tl_set:Nn \l__guido_temp_tl { \group_begin: \footnotesize }
  \tl_map_inline:Nn \l__guido_text_tl
   {
    \token_if_eq_meaning:NNTF ##1 \q_space
     {
      \tl_put_right:Nn \l__guido_temp_tl { ~ }
     }
     {
      \int_compare:nTF { \char_value_uccode:n { `##1 } = `##1 }
       {
        \tl_put_right:Nn \l__guido_temp_tl { {\normalsize ##1} }
       }
       {
        \tl_put_right:Nn \l__guido_temp_tl { \tl_upper_case:n { ##1 } }
       }
     }
   }
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l__guido_temp_tl { \group_end: }
 }
\quark_new:N \q_space
\tl_new:N \l__guido_text_tl
\tl_new:N \l__guido_temp_tl
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\fakesc[\mytitle]{This is the title}

\title{\mytitle}
\author{An Author}
\maketitle


\fakesc{All inside this are fake caps} and this is normal

\end{document}
```

But this is just a hack and *real* small caps should be preferred. The argument to `\fakesc` *must* consist only of letters and spaces. No fancy characters or commands.

[image]

Comment: Who's guido (from `\guido_fakes`)?

Comment: @einpoklum Guido is the questioner; I usually take the OP's nickname for the prefix.

Comment: I have problem to use the command in `\@makeschapterhead`. It worked in `\@makechapterhead` but not in the stared version. Maybe some problem with table of contents.

Comment: @Sigur Since this code doesn't use `\@makechapterhead` and I can't imagine how you're using it, it's difficult to say. Anyway, using faked small caps is the very last resort, better using a font that has the real thing.

Comment: @egreg, yes, I agree. But unfortunately the editor uses a font without small caps, so I have to fake it. I redefined the chapter head from the book class to change the font and I use `\fakesc{#1}` inside its definition. It worked for numbered but no for the stared one. Strange. If you have time I can try to make a mwe.

Comment: @Sigur New question, please

Comment: @egreg, done. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/473637/14757