# Any tricks to mock small caps in Atkinson font

Tags: fonts, small-caps

The `\atkinson` package provides me with my font of choice given its better visibility and clear distinction between small i, capital I and small l. Also, there is good distinction between 0, o and O.

However, the package does not support small caps which is generally how I like to style my section heading. Is there a trick of hack I can do to make `atkinson` behave the way I want? I tried something (in the MWE), but it does not work and certainly not extensible to a whole document.

In the minimal code below:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{atkinson}

\begin{document}
\textsc{The Grass is Green} \par

T\scriptsize{HE} \normalsize{G}\scriptsize{RASS} \scriptsize{IS} \normalsize{G}\scriptsize{REEN}.

\end{document}
```

The output is given below where the second line is somewhat close to what I want and need the `\textsc{}` command to do.
[image: Small_caps]

Comment: note `\scriptsize{HE}` makes the rest of the document scriptsize, not just HE

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/85143/1090