# Bold small caps with XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX

Tags: luatex, small-caps

I am having some issues with `LuaLaTex` and/or `fontenc` and bold small caps while using the Adobe Garamond Pro font. Here are my files:

[image]

When I compile with XeLaTeX and these options:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{Adobe Garamond Pro}
```

Everything works fine (except for the italic small caps, but I have no use for it):

[image]

But when I try to compile with LuaLaTeX and these options:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[%
    Path           = /home/.../Fonts/Adobe Garamond Pro/,
    Extension      = .otf,
    Ligatures      = TeX,
    BoldFont       = AGaramondPro-Bold,
    ItalicFont     = AGaramondPro-Italic,
    BoldItalicFont = AGaramondPro-BoldItalic,
]{AGaramondPro-Regular}
```

Bold small caps don't work:

[image]

Here is the log:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `EU2/AGaramondPro-Regular(0)/bx/sc' undefined
(Font)        using `EU2/AGaramondPro-Regular(0)/bx/n' instead on input 
line 31.

[1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./smallcaps.aux)

LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults
substituted.
```

I looked into the `fontspec` manual and did not find anything that solved this issue. Clearly it's not font-related because XeLaTeX manage to produce bold small caps but not LuaLaTeX.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you check the files with ``otfinfo -f`` you will see that the neither the bold nor the italic variant provide small caps. The Xetex output might due to some fake bold trickery.

Comment: Related to @phg's comment, check [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55664/10102) on how to produce fake small caps.

Comment: @phg: Neither XeTeX nor `fontspec` do fake fonts by default (`fontspec` manual even discourages using them).

Comment: @Khaled Hosny then OP has a different version of the font. I personally have only limited access to those fonts so I can’t really test them.

Comment: I bypassed my issue by using a different font for my titlepage (only part where I need bold small caps). For now it'll work.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the OP has adopted a work-around which does not answer the original question but the original problem probably depends on some oddity in a commercial font not generally accessible. (Or it is a duplicate of one of the linked questions but we can't tell which without the font and the OP is no longer interested in the answer.)