# Improved fake small caps

Tags: small-caps

Fonts that do not have real small caps simply scale down capital letters when you use `\textsc`. This looks unbalanced, as the letters are too thin. Can this be improved?

Comment: Not really. Avoid small caps if the real thing is not available.

Comment: Strongly related: [Fake small caps with XeTeX/fontspec?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55664/430)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One idea is to simply scale down capitals and then "fatten" them, which in my opinion looks much better than simple scaling. The fattening can be implemented by copying and shifting by a small amount several times. This example uses the `fourier` font, which doesn't include real small caps.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, pdftex]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\fakesc}[1]{\textls[100]{\rlap{\scalebox{0.8}[0.75]{#1}}\hskip0.02ex\rlap{\scalebox{0.8}[0.75]{#1}}\hskip0.02ex\scalebox{0.8}[0.75]{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\noindent
Lorem Ipsum \textsc{Lorem Ipsum} Lorem Ipsum \\
Lorem Ipsum L\fakesc{OREM} I\fakesc{PSUM} Lorem Ipsum
\end{document}
```

Here is a pictorial view:

[image: Improved small caps]

This solution is not perfect. Vertical serifs (like in the E above) tend to become too thick, and diagonal strokes that were the same thickness as vertical strokes are no longer of the same thickness (like in the M above). However, I think these objections are minor, and the final result is better than the standard fake small caps.

Comment: Purists will not like this solution, but I'm not a purist...+1

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I think your modification makes the letters look a bit too narrow. With my values, I tried to make the vertical strokes of the letters to be approximately the same for the normal letters and the fake small caps.

Comment: Understood.  I will delete the prior comment forthwith.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes learning new words on tex.se, that's a thing for me, now.

Comment: @thymaro Language is fun, as long as one does not become omphaloskeptic about it.

Comment: This is such a useful answer, but I wonder: is it possible to have `\fakesc` behave like `\textsc` for mixed case arguments? That is `\fakesc{Lorem Ipsum}`?.

My use case is as follows: I use a variant of the `metropolis` theme in Beamer, but I use `MyriadPro` and `mdsymbol` packages instead of Fira Sans. I like Myriad Pro with coordinated symbols for presentations. But Myriad Pro does not have proper small caps, so I can't currently support two of the title format options provided my the metropolis theme.

Comment: @GTK That is possible, but requires a bit of programming. Maybe you should make it into a separate question.