# No greek small caps with Libertine (pdflatex)

Tags: pdftex, greek, small-caps, libertine

I'm trying to get libertine small caps to work with greek, with the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
%\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenx}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

\usepackage{libertine}
%\usepackage{libertinegc}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{greek}
\textsc{Τα Πεζοκεφαλαία δεν δουλεύουν.}
\end{document}
```

but instead it fails and reverts back to the regular font. In their website they seem to have small caps working with greek, but in pdflatex they don't seem to work.

Comment: The glyphs shown on the site are faked small caps.

Comment: English small caps work though

Comment: Which website are you referring to?

Comment: @user51830 http://www.linuxlibertine.org/index.php?id=86&L=1

Comment: @svart Yes: Latin letters have the small caps variant; Greek ones don't.

Comment: My `\fauxsc` macro might be of use.  See, for example, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171470/good-small-caps-font-to-use-with-arev/171545#171545 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55664/fake-small-caps-with-xetex-fontspec/225078#225078