# Make small caps fall back to faux small caps when sc shape is unavailable

Tags: fonts, small-caps

Is it possible to redefine the `\textsc` command to fall back to [faux small caps](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171470/good-small-caps-font-to-use-with-arev/171545#171545) when a `sc` shape is unavailable with the current font?