# Glossaries and fake small caps using fontspec

Tags: fontspec, glossaries, small-caps

I want to use faked small caps when doing a list of abbreviations using the `glossaries` package. I am using another font but for reproducibility purposes in this example I have used `Linux Libertine O`. To make things clearer I have also exaggerated the scaling factor in this example. For some reason it seems sometimes my `\smallCaps` command works fine but in this case it doesn't go back again. What am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newcommand{\smallCaps}[1]{%
    {\fontspec[Scale=0.5]{Linux Libertine O} #1}%
}

\setacronymstyle{long-short}
\begin{document}

%ABBREVIATIONS
\newacronym{ADR}{\smallCaps{ADR}}{adverse drug reaction}

\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
Works \smallCaps{FOO} does not work: \gls{ADR}). A more specific definition
for the term \gls{ADR} is 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55664/fake-small-caps-with-xetex-fontspec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never use `\fontspec` inside the document; it's a generic command used by the user level commands `\setmainfont`, `\newfontfamily` and similar. Also `\setmainfont` should only be used in the preamble.

I removed the `\setmainfont` declaration just to show how the font is chosen independently of the main font. The key is to use the `short` key in `\newacronym`.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newcommand{\smallCaps}[1]{%
    {\fontspec[Scale=0.5]{Linux Libertine O} #1}%
}

\setacronymstyle{long-short}
\begin{document}

%ABBREVIATIONS
\newacronym{ADR}{\smallCaps{ADR}}{adverse drug reaction}

\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
Works \smallCaps{FOO} does not work: \gls{ADR}). A more specific definition
for the term \gls{ADR} is 

\end{document}
```

[image]

On the other hand, a better strategy (assuming you have no other way to produce small caps) is to add it in the font definition:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}[
  SmallCapsFont={Linux Libertine O},
  SmallCapsFeatures={Scale=0.5},
]

\setacronymstyle{long-short}
\begin{document}

%ABBREVIATIONS
\newacronym[
  short=\textsc{ADR}
]{ADR}{ADR}{adverse drug reaction}

Works \textsc{FOO} does not work: \gls{ADR}). A more specific definition
for the term \gls{ADR} is

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Finally, the best strategy if you don't have real small caps is to avoid them altogether.

Comment: Sadly it doesn't seem to play nice together with fakeslant though... :(

Comment: @jonalv Don't fake. ;-) Above all, don't use slanted type.

Comment: I use them to mark strange commercial names on things which I want to mark somewhat in the text to make it clear that "Yes it's actually called that, don't blame me" :)

Comment: @jonalv Please, open a new question with a detailed example.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228831/fake-slant-and-fake-small-caps-by-scaling-does-not-play-nice-together-with-fonts