# Make small caps the same size as lowercase

Tags: fontsize

Letters in small caps (`\scshape`) are larger (height and width) than lower case letters. How can you make them the same size?

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Default: \textsc{a}a, \textsc{b}b, \textsc{c}c \dots
Solution should look more like this: \textsc{\footnotesize a}a, 
  \textsc{\footnotesize b}b, \textsc{\footnotesize c}c \dots
\end{document}
```

Comment: Isn't this exactly the purpose of small caps??? -- to have a greater height than the lower case letters? ;-)

Comment: I think it looks better if they are the same size. Some older books are typeset that way.

Comment: Mixing them does not look nice anyway -- is there any reason you want to have them this way?

Comment: I'm using `scshape` for theorem headings, and I don't want the size of the lower case letters to change in the middle of a paragraph.

Comment: I also don't think this is a good idea. But you can easily adapt one of the solutions in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55664/fake-small-caps-with-xetex-fontspec/64584#64584 to achieve what you want.

Comment: Easily done with `fontspec`. But why not use a font designed in such a way that the small caps are to your liking. 'Faking' font sizes usually looks obvious and not in a good way.

Comment: *Fake* small-caps look especially bad this way which is why `fontinst` does not match fake small-caps to the size of loawercase. (I think it uses 80% of uppercase height, but might be misremembering.)

Comment: Note also: the size of the lowercase letters does *not* change. Small-caps are *not* lowercase letters. But, really, if you prefer small-caps of similar size, just use a font which is designed that way.

Answer (score 7):

It would be much better to choose a font designed to your liking. Obviously, this depends on more than just the size of small-caps, but here's one example,

```
\usepackage{kpfonts}
```

[image: kpfonts small-caps and lowercase]

Note that no font will make them the same *width* since the shapes of upper and lowercase letters differ and, hence, so do those of small-caps and lowercase. But I assume you can't really want small-caps `i` to be the same width as lowercase `i`....