# Small Caps not working for non-LaTeX font

Tags: fonts, formatting, luatex, small-caps

I'm using a special font called 'Brandon Grotesque' (it has to be exactly that one) for a presentation based on the Beamer class.

When trying to get small caps output, it doesn't work. I'm using LuaLatex as a compiler.

In general I'm aware of the possibility that the specific font might not contain small caps, but when using the font in e.g. Powerpoint, the small caps work.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{xltxtra}

\setmainfont[BoldFont={Brandon Grotesque Bold},Renderer=Basic]{Brandon Grotesque}
\setsansfont{Brandon Grotesque}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
Normal Output
\textsc{Small Caps}
\textbf{Bold Text}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps Powerpoint fakes small caps. It's also possible to do that with `fontspec` it seems, see e.g. [Fake small caps with XeTeX/fontspec?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55664)/ and linked questions.

Comment: I don't see them in 
http://hvdfonts.com/assets/Document/6/Specimen_Brandon.pdf

Comment: Even if it has small caps, does it have bold small caps? But the most likely reason is that ppt is faking them. Also, you need to tell Beamer not to mess with the fonts if you don't want it to by loading the `professional` font theme.