# Defined command only works in preamble

Tags: macros, errors, documentclass-writing

I'm writing a class, and when using it I want to use small caps with a font that doesn't have small caps defined (I know – not as good as the real thing). I found this answer [Fake small caps with XeTeX/fontspec?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55664/fake-small-caps-with-xetex-fontspec/225078#225078) which I tried to include, however I get the errors:

`Missing $ inserted. 
Missing $ inserted. 
You can't use '\spacefactor' in vertical mode.`

However, the code works perfectly when it's pasted into the preamble.

Anyone know what's going on?

### MWE

#### Class File

```
\ProvidesClass{custom}[a custom class]
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

\DeclareOption*{
    \PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{scrreprt}
}
\ProcessOptions\relax

\LoadClass[usegeometry]{scrreprt}


\RequirePackage{graphicx}

\RequirePackage{plex-serif}

% Small Caps

\makeatletter
\newlength\fake@f
\newlength\fake@c
\def\fakesc#1{%
\begingroup%
\xdef\fake@name{\csname\curr@fontshape/\f@size\endcsname}%
\fontsize{\fontdimen8\fake@name}{\baselineskip}\selectfont%
\uppercase{#1}%
\endgroup%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand\fauxsc[1]{\fauxschelper#1 \relax\relax}
\def\fauxschelper#1 #2\relax{%
\fauxschelphelp#1\relax\relax%
\if\relax#2\relax\else\ \fauxschelper#2\relax\fi%
}
\def\Hscale{.83}\def\Vscale{.72}\def\Cscale{1.00}
\def\fauxschelphelp#1#2\relax{%
\ifnum`#1>``\ifnum`#1<`\{\scalebox{\Hscale}[\Vscale]{\uppercase{#1}}\else%
    \scalebox{\Cscale}[1]{#1}\fi\else\scalebox{\Cscale}[1]{#1}\fi%
\ifx\relax#2\relax\else\fauxschelphelp#2\relax\fi}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\maketitleee}{
    \fauxsc{\@title}
}
\makeatother
```

#### Document

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{custom}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}

\begin{document}

\maketitleee

\end{document}
```

### Update

Removing all the `\makeatletter`s and `\makeatother`s seems to change the errors given to those below

[image: Errors]

### Update 2

This was fixed by @moewe's suggestion, which is replacing `\fauxsc{\@title}` with `\expandafter\fauxsc\expandafter{\@title}`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  Without seeing your code it is impossible to say what the problem is. Can you please add a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. The code should compile and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. Cutting your code down to a MWE may well reveal what your problem actually is. In any case, it is really difficult to help you without more information.

Comment: I'm  not sure about the 'missing `$` inserted' errors, but the 'You can't use '\spacefactor' in vertical mode.' comes up when you try to use or (re-)define a command name beginning with `@` without using `\makeatletter...\makeatother`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351/35864 (note how the answer in the linked question has `\makeatletter...\makeatother` around all commands with `@` in their names). Class files and `.sty` files are automatically processed with `\makeatletter` on, which would explain why a command can be defined and used there, but not in the document.

Comment: @Andrew I've added some more info. Let me know if you'd like anything else.

Comment: I can't reproduce the errors you get, but if your code is the complete .cls file, there probably should be a `\LoadClass{article}` call at the beginning to load the basic LaTeX commands defined in the base classes

Comment: please don't just post disconnected code fragments, post a single small example that we can run to get the error that you are asking about, otherwise it's very hard to guess the error and advise how to fix it.

Comment: As David says, please post a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228): the code should be as small as possible so as to reproduce your error. You should either post a **minimal**  latex document that exhibits the problem or, alternatively, a **minimal** class file together with a **minimal** latex document. The key thing is that we should be able to reproduce your error from the code that you post. It is virtually impossible to help you if you don't show us the problem.

Comment: Sorry about that. I think I've got the message now. You should find a *complete* MWE in the description now.

Comment: your definition of `\maketitleee` should have the `\makeatletter/\makeatother` *outside*, not inside. There might be other problems (code looks complicated).

Comment: Within the *class file* (`.cls`) you should not have to use `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` at all - remove them.

Comment: @moewe No redefinition is done to `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`.

Comment: @egreg I checked the sources shortly after I wrote that and saw that there are no redefinitions, so I removed that claim.

Comment: Without `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` the macro doesn't work. Moving them outside did change the errors I was getting though, and now they won't go away even if I move that bit into the preamble. Seems like `fakesc` doesn't like being surrounded by `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`.

Comment: If I remove the `\makeatletter`...`\makeatother`s (both pairs) and change to a different font (I don't have Plex installed), the MWE compiles fine without errors, the output also seems to be as expected. If you get an error or different problems when you remove the `\makeat...`s, please update your question accordingly.

Comment: @moewe It seems me simplifying things removed a cause of an error. I've updated the MWE.

Comment: There still is a `\makeatletter` and a `\makeatother` in your `.cls` file. **Remove *all* `\makeatletter`s and `\makeatother`s from the `.cls`.** As I said before if I remove all of them (in the earlier version two pairs, now only one pair), the MWE compiles.

Comment: That's strange. I've had a different experience, here's my modified MWE https://pastebin.com/JQnU79xA which is giving me different errors.

Comment: Well that is an *entirely* different matter. In your earlier code you did not have `\fauxsc` around the `\@title`. The implementation of `\fauxsc` seems to impose conditions on its argument, try `\expandafter\fauxsc\expandafter{\@title}` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First and foremost: faking small caps for a font that hasn't them is hopeless.

---

When LaTeX is reading a `.cls` file, `\makeatletter` is implicitly in force and issuing `\makeatother` will most likely introduce problems.

Indeed it does, because when we arrive at defining `\maketitlee`, `@` is an “other character”, so the definition becomes

```
• •\makeatletter•\@•t•i•t•l•e•\makeatother•
```

(`•` is used to separate tokens). Note that when `\maketitlee` is called, the replacement text has already been tokenized, so `\makeatletter` will do nothing at all.

Never use `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` in a `.cls` file except in the *body* of a macro definition that has among its actions inputting a file where the special treatment of `@` is needed. This is not the case of your `\maketitlee` macro.

---

After removing `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` everywhere in the class file, compiling your example `.tex` file produces no error and the output is

[image]

that clearly shows what I mean in the top line of this answer.

Comment: I see, however — if I remove the `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` it doesn't work.

Comment: @tecosaur I tried, of course.

Comment: Something that may throw a spanner in the works, after seeing this comment https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/459738/defined-command-only-works-in-preamble/459749?noredirect=1#comment1156092_459738 I realised I needed to modify the MWE given, for me that MWE doesn't successfully compile.

Comment: However, this does solve the issue which I had (at least the first one). Thanks :)

Comment: In some situations better than `\makeatletter..\makeatother` is: `\begingroup\makeatletter\@firstofone{\endgroup <Stuff where @ must be letter>}` . This way the category code of `@` will be reset to whatever it was before issuing the `\makeatletter`-command. `\makeatother` does set the category code of `@` to 12 (other) no matter what it was before.