# Use \fauxsc if small caps not avaiaible

Tags: fonts

I tend to use the IBM Plex font, which does not have small caps — hence I get this message when trying to use `\textsc`: *Font shape `T1/IBMPlexSerif-TLF/m/fscn' undefined (Font)  using`T1/IBMPlexSerif-TLF/m/n' instead.*

To get around this I use `\fauxsc` ([Fake small caps with XeTeX/fontspec?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55664/fake-small-caps-with-xetex-fontspec/225078#225078)), which seems to work in pdflatex.

What would be really snazzy though would be to extend the functionality of `\textsc` such that when the font *does* have small caps, it just uses that; then when it doesn't (e.g. as happens with IBM Plex) instead of giving an error, it *automatically* switches to using `\fauxsc`

Would such a thing be possible?

Comment: Using faked small caps will ruin your document.

Comment: I imagine by "ruin your document" you mean it won't be as good as true small caps?

Comment: Just look at the picture in my answer: the difference in stroke weight is apparent and ugly.

Comment: Yea. I know (and can clearly see) what you're talking about. What's nice with Plex though is it's got a good variety of different weights available. Now I just need a way to make the smaller letters be one weight higher.

Comment: @egreg if this is of interest, this is what I ended up with: https://i.postimg.cc/JzyVgKd7/image.png by using this https://pastebin.com/SDGfBZ3d

Comment: Seems a decent result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a possible solution, but if you really need small caps, use a font that has them.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{plex-serif}
\usepackage{roboto}

\let\textsc\relax
\DeclareRobustCommand{\textsc}[1]{%
  \sbox0{x\xdef\testA{\the\font}}%
  \sbox0{\scshape x\xdef\testB{\the\font}}%
  \ifx\testA\testB\fauxsc{#1}\else{\scshape #1}\fi
}

\makeatletter
\newlength\fake@f
\newlength\fake@c
\def\fakesc#1{%
  \begingroup
  \xdef\fake@name{\csname\curr@fontshape/\f@size\endcsname}%
  \fontsize{\fontdimen8\fake@name}{\baselineskip}\selectfont
  \MakeUppercase{#1}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
\newcommand\fauxsc[1]{\fauxschelper#1 \relax\relax}
\def\fauxschelper#1 #2\relax{%
  \fauxschelphelp#1\relax\relax
  \if\relax#2\relax\else\ \fauxschelper#2\relax\fi
}
\def\Hscale{.83}\def\Vscale{.72}\def\Cscale{1.00}
\def\fauxschelphelp#1#2\relax{%
  \ifnum`#1>``\ifnum`#1<`\{\scalebox{\Hscale}[\Vscale]{\uppercase{#1}}\else
    \scalebox{\Cscale}[1]{#1}\fi\else\scalebox{\Cscale}[1]{#1}\fi
  \ifx\relax#2\relax\else\fauxschelphelp#2\relax\fi}

\begin{document}

\textsc{Abc def}

\sffamily % this has true small caps

\textsc{Abc def}

\end{document}
```

The idea is to compare what font gets chosen if `\scshape` is applied. In case LaTeX performs a substitution, `\testA` and `\testB` will both point to the same font.

[image]

Comment: This does not seem to work for me. I'm using it with geschichtsfrkl bibliography, and I'm getting a few strange errors:
```document.tex:186: Improper alphabetic constant.
<to be read again> 
                   \MakeLowercase 
l.186 ...rung bewältigen.\cite{2012SchIg}

document.tex:186: Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.186 ...rung bewältigen.\cite{2012SchIg}

document.tex:186: Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.186 ...rung bewältigen.\cite{2012SchIg}```
(And some more every \cite)

Comment: @nleanba Oh, the trick for emulating small caps has several limitations and you found one. Use a font that has real small caps and forget about this.