# How to add small caps to the headers?

Tags: fonts, small-caps

I'd like to add some small caps to the headers. How could I do that?
This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Baskerville}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}   
\pagestyle{fancy}
% We don't want chapter and section numbers
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{} % sets both header and footer to nothing
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[CE]{\textsc{A title}} % even pages: chapter title
\fancyhead[CO]{\textsc{\leftmark}} % odd pages: book title

\begin{document}

\chapter{A title}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Baskerville doesn't seem to have pre-defined small caps.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a general method for obtaining small caps with custom fonts?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/262584/is-there-a-general-method-for-obtaining-small-caps-with-custom-fonts)

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/225078/ may also be of interest (apparently it works with pdflatex as well)

Comment: If your font is lacking small caps, one might consider fudging it: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55664/fake-small-caps-with-xetex-fontspec

Comment: If smallcaps not available in font family, then please follow one of a beautiful suggestion gave by the great `egreg` `how to create fake small caps`, refer https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/499007/use-fauxsc-if-small-caps-not-avaiaible