# How to get smallcaps for a font that doesn't support it?

Tags: fonts, fontspec, small-caps

I have a few artistic fonts that I use in XeLaTeX with the fontspec package. However, they don't support smallcaps out of the box.

Is there a way to tell LaTeX to "fake" smallcaps by capitalizing everything and scaling the lowercase letters down a bit, similar to how Word or OpenOffice do it?

Minimal example, even though it's pretty obvious:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{fontspec}

% Really any font that doesn't include small caps definitions
\newfontfamily\titlefont{Old London Alternate}

\begin{document}
\titlefont \scshape Test Text
\end{document}
```

The Test Text is not rendered in small caps, as it would be if the font supported small caps.

Thanks for pointing me to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55664/fake-small-caps-with-xetex-fontspec), which works fine in general, but has the drawback that it fails on UTF-8 encoded files with non-ASCII characters, which I need to use. If you have an idea how to modify that answer to also support non-ascii characters, please let me know.

Comment: Personally I think that faking small caps is a bad typographic choice, so I'd rather look for a compatible font that offers small caps. However, the answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55664/fake-small-caps-with-xetex-fontspec) offer many ways to do it if you really want to.

Comment: In TUGboat, we find the default small caps too small for acronyms, so we have defined "big small caps" by using smaller sizes of ordinary caps.  The code is in `ltugboat.cls` (on CTAN), and you are welcome to adapt it.  This mode *does* lack the wider sidebearings usually associated with "designed" small caps.

Comment: I found a way to modify it: you need to replace the `\def\fauxschelp` part up to `\begin{document}` with the following: `\def\fauxschelphelp#1#2\relax{\ifnum\`#1=\uccode\`#1\relax\scalebox{\Cscale}[1]{#1}\else\scalebox{\Hscale}[\Vscale]{\uppercase{#1}}\fi\ifx\relax#2\relax\else\fauxschelphelp#2\relax\fi}`

Comment: The problem with the other solution was that it checks if the character is a lowercase letter simply by checking if its character code is within a certain range (`A-Z`), which makes all non-ASCII characters be treated like uppercase letters (so they are not capitalized, for example). I changed it to use the uppercase code of the character instead.