# Apply special formatting to capital letters in expl3

Tags: expl3, programming, small-caps

In my attempt to learn `expl3` programming, I've hacked together a function to fake "smallcaps" by looping through a token list and enlarging any tokens that are capital letters. The code currently "works", but I know I have jumped through more hoops than I needed to. My question is: *how can I rewrite the code to better use what `expl3` has to offer?*

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_if_eq:nnTF { VV }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_to_str:n { e }

\DeclareDocumentCommand\fakesmallcaps{m} {
    \tl_new:N \__orig_tl
    \tl_new:N \__modified_tl

    \tl_set:Nn \__orig_tl {#1}
    % Put all the spaces in groups so they don't get filtered out when we map over them.
    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \__orig_tl { ~ } { {~} }

    \tl_set:Nn \__modified_tl {
        \tl_map_inline:Nn \__orig_tl {
            \tl_set:Nn \__current_tl {##1}
            \tl_set:NV \__uppercasecurrent_tl {\tl_upper_case:n {##1}}

            \str_set:Nx \__orig_str {\tl_to_str:e {\__current_tl}}
            \str_set:Nx \__uppercasecurrent_str {\tl_to_str:e {\__uppercasecurrent_tl}}

            \tl_if_eq:VVTF {\__orig_str} {\__uppercasecurrent_str} {
                {\Large \__orig_str}
            }{
                \__uppercasecurrent_str
            }
        }
    }

    \tl_use:N \__modified_tl
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\fakesmallcaps{This Is Cool}
```

I am aware of solutions using regular expressions [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55664/fake-small-caps-with-xetex-fontspec), but I really want to "loop through the tokens". I have also tried and failed to create an `\bool__iscapital:n` function macro that can be used inside of `\bool_if:nTF`, so guidance on that would be appreciated! It would also be a huge plus if I could do something like `\fakesmallcaps{{\color{blue}The} Windy Road}` and have the color preserved.

Answer (score 1):

Here, instead of using expl3, I use my `tokcycle` package to cycle through the tokens.  To each *appropriate* token, I apply `\fauxsctok`, which mimics my approach in the cited question, [Fake small caps with XeTeX/fontspec?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55664/fake-small-caps-with-xetex-fontspec).

The advantage of using `tokcycle` to the approach in the referenced question is that macros and spaces can be echoed without trying to apply small caps to them.  Further, the small-capping can extend *into* groups within the environment.

The difficulty is that one cannot *blindly* small-cap each cat-11 token, but only those that are to be typeset.  So, in `\color{blue}`, we wish to avoid applying typesetting commands to `blue`, since it is a macro argument and not text for typesetting!

In general, TeX has no way of knowing if (and how many) arguments are associated with a macro.  So, here, I have to program the list of macro names that might appear in the environment, requiring a non-typesettable argument.  In this implementation, I limit that list to macros requiring the "protection" of a single argument.  The macros programmed into the current list are `\color` and `\textcolor`.  While the latter takes two arguments, only the first argument needs to be protected from typesetting.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor,tokcycle,graphicx}
\def\Hscale{.83}\def\Vscale{.72}\def\Cscale{1.00}
\newif\ifskiparg
\newcommand\fauxsctok[1]{%
  \ifnum`#1>``\ifnum`#1<`\{\scalebox{\Hscale}[\Vscale]{\uppercase{#1}}\else%
    \scalebox{\Cscale}[1]{#1}\fi\else\scalebox{\Cscale}[1]{#1}\fi}
\tokcycleenvironment\fauxsc
  {\addcytoks{\fauxsctok{##1}}}% CHARACTER DIRECTIVE
  {\ifskiparg\addcytoks{##1}\else\processtoks{##1}\fi\aftergroup
    \skipargfalse}% GROUP DIRECTIVE
  {\addcytoks{##1}%
   \ifx\color##1\skipargtrue\fi
   \ifx\textcolor##1\skipargtrue\fi
  }% MACRO DIRECTIVE
  {\addcytoks{##1}}% SPACE DIRECTIVE
\begin{document}
\fauxsc{\color{blue}The} Windy Road

\textcolor{blue}{The} Windy Road\endfauxsc
\ and back to normal.
\end{document}
```

[image]

The `fauxsc` pseudo-environment builds a token list (`\cytoks`) by cycling through the tokens of the environment.  **Characters** (things not catcode 0,1,2,10) have `\fauxsctok` applied to them (inside the `\cytoks` token list being built).

If a **Group** is encountered when `\ifskiparg` is set true, then the group is merely echoed to `\cytoks` without alteration. However, when `\ifskiparg` is false, each token of the group will be processed through the token cycle.  In either event, `\ifskiparg` is reset false after the group concludes.

**Macros** are merely echoed into `\cytoks`.  However, then the macro name has to be compared against the programmed list to see whether `\ifskiparg` needs to be set true.  Finally,

**Spaces** that are encountered are merely echoed into `\cytoks`.