# How can I make it so that all the letters on a word are all capitalized yet the first letter is bigger than the rest?

Tags: fonts, fontsize, capitalization, small-caps

How can I make it so that all the letters on a word are capitalized yet the first letter is bigger than the rest?

An example would be the first and second word on the following image:

[image: Example of what's being described]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `\textsc{Definicion...}`  It is called "small-caps"

Comment: This kind of formatting is probably a theorem style, by the way. That lets you number your definitions or put in page references to them. And you can change the formatting of all your definitions at once.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The style is called "small caps" and is considered a font *shape* by LaTeX.  Thus, `\scshape` will turn it on, or a delimited form, `\textsc{...}` is available.  Naturally, you must make sure your font supports this shape.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\textsc{Definici\'on (Isomorfismo)} Sea $T:U\rightarrow V$
\end{document}
```

[image]

p.s.  Other font shapes include italic (`\itshape`) and upright (`\upshape`).

Comment: +1 even if you used `:` instead of `\colon` `;-)`

Comment: As far as I remember, in a small caps variant of a font the lowercase letters are not just smaller capital letters, but the stroke width is also adjusted to match the uppercase letters. Thus, you would not get the same result if you just played with uppercase letters in different font sizes.

Comment: @Dubu It is true that small caps are not merely scaled caps.  My answer here, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55664/fake-small-caps-with-xetex-fontspec/225078#225078, talks a little about that.  The approach suggested was to have a different scaling ratio for vertical versus horizontal scaling.  But even that does not create a true small cap, which is actually a separate font created by a font designer, and not merely a mathematical manipulation of the base font.